# Call a method using a literal in javaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to do something like this,

`"abc".reverse();`

this should return `"cba"`

where I have defined the function reverse

```
function reverse(){
   //algorithm to revere abc
}
```

don't confuse reverse() with predefined function.

Is this possible in JavaScript

Comment: What's wrong with `reverse("abc")` ?  But you could attach your function to the prototype of String.

Comment: You'd need to modify String.prototype, but I'd advise against it. Thilo's suggestion is a better idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a method on the prototype, however this is often considered bad practice outside of personal projects, as it can be confusing for other developers.

```
String.prototype.reverse = function() {
  return this.split('').reverse().join('')
}

"abc".reverse() // => "cba"
```